# Javascript select doesn't work the way I want

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple selects on my site and every single one has to have his individual javascript code for it to work, which bothers me and I have no clue how I can fix it. My code handles every single select and makes it disapear after user clicks something different than select or chooses option from select. It also makes a problem where I have to make separate CSS styling for every select. Please give me some hints how to make it work.

```js
const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");
var modal = document.getElementById("selected");
const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

const selected2 = document.querySelector(".selected2");
const optionsContainer2 = document.querySelector(".options-container2");
var modal2 = document.getElementById("selected2");
const optionsList2 = document.querySelectorAll(".option2");

var offScreen = document.getElementById("add-node-window");

selected.addEventListener("click", () => {
  optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
});

selected2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  optionsContainer2.classList.toggle("active");
});

optionsList.forEach((o) => {
  o.addEventListener("click", () => {
    selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
    o.querySelector("input").checked = true;
    optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
  });
});

optionsList2.forEach((o) => {
  o.addEventListener("click", () => {
    selected2.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
    o.querySelector("input").checked = true;
    optionsContainer2.classList.remove("active");
  });
});
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target != modal) {
    optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
  }
  if (event.target != modal2) {
    optionsContainer2.classList.remove("active");
  }
};

const addNodeBtn = document.querySelector(".add-node-btn");
```

```css
.select-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.select-box .options-container {
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  order: 1;
  min-width: 10rem;
}

.selected {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
  order: 0;
  min-width: 10rem;
}

.selected::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("/static/bx-chevron-down.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 32px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;

  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.select-box .options-container.active + .selected::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  top: -6px;
}

.select-box .options-container.active {
  max-height: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.select-box .option,
.selected {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: start;
}

.select-box .option:hover {
  background: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

.select-box .option .radio {
  display: none;
}

.select-box label {
  cursor: pointer;
}


.select-box2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.select-box2 .options-container2 {
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  order: 1;
  min-width: 10rem;
}

.selected2 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
  order: 0;
  min-width: 10rem;
}

.selected2::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("/static/bx-chevron-down.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 32px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;

  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.select-box2 .options-container2.active + .selected2::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  top: -6px;
}

.select-box2 .options-container2.active {
  max-height: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.select-box2 .option2,
.selected2 {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: start;
}

.select-box2 .option2:hover {
  background: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

.select-box2 .option2 .radio2 {
  display: none;
}

.select-box2 label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-container" id="select-container">
    <div class="select-box" id="select-box">
      <div class="options-container" id="options-container">
        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="time-asc" name="category" />
          <label for="time-asc">Time ascending</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="time-dsc" name="category" />
          <label for="time-dsc">Time descending</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="reward-asc" name="category" />
          <label for="reward-asc">Reward ascending</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="reward-dsc" name="category" />
          <label for="reward-dsc">Reward descending</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="selected" id="selected">Sort</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="select-container2">
    <div class="select-box2">
      <div class="options-container2">
        <div class="option2">
          <input type="radio" class="radio2" id="by-user" name="category" />
          <label for="by-user">By User</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option2">
          <input type="radio" class="radio2" id="by-category" name="category" />
          <label for="by-category">By Category</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="selected2" id="selected2">Filtr</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

As far as the CSS goes, you can modify it so that each block targets BOTH select lists instead of repeating it all:

```
.select-box,
.select-box2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
```

Assuming these two select lists will always be styled the same, this will save lines of CSS, reduce the chance that you update the style of one and forget the other, and in general is a best practice when it comes to writing CSS.

I suspect your are looking to do the same type of thing with your javascript. The solution will be similar except that with js you will put the code in a function, and call the function when you are add the event listeners like this:

```
const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");

function toggleActive() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
}

selected.addEventListener( "click", toggleActive );
selected2.addEventListener( "click", toggleActive );
```

This isn't the exact code you need - but this is the approach you need to take to avoid writing the same JS multiple times.